# I want to get TextView reference in class but i get exceptions

Tags: java, android

Here is the code for my mainActivity.java file

I am trying to access the reference of textview in class MyGestureListener but i am unable to do this because every time my application unfortunately stopped on scroll gesture.
**here is my code**

This is my main class

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
TextView myText;
Button myButton;
private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myText);
    myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new MyGestureListener());

    myButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myText.setText("I am clicked from button");
        }
    });

}

public TextView getTextView()
{

    TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myText);
    return txtView;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

}

**This is my user defined class**

class   extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

```
private TextView myText;
MainActivity m;

public MyGestureListener(){

    m = new MainActivity();


}
//MainActivity m = new MainActivity();
@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {

    myText.setText("Scroll ho v ja hun");

    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You must not create any Activity objects yourself, as you do in the  MyGestureListener constructor. They are created by Android.

Also in MyGestureListener the TextView is never initialised.

You should instead pass a reference to the TextView when you initialise a MyGestureListener object.

For example you can do something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView myText;
    Button myButton;
    private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myText);
        myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
        mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new MyGestureListener(myText));

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myText.setText("I am clicked from button");
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}

class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private TextView myText;

    public MyGestureListener(TextView textView) {
        myText = textView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {

        myText.setText("Scroll ho v ja hun");

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i do that i am new to android please guide me with defined code

Answer (score 0):

You are never setting the myText MyGestureListener class. Try this:

```
myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myText);
mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new MyGestureListener());
mDetector.myText = myText;
```

For the code above to work myText will have to be public.

So change this: 
    private TextView myText;

to this:

```
public TextView myText;
```